# Updating a column in a table with values from a collection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to make an update of a multiple columns in a table with values from a PL/SQL collection that I've created.

So I declare a table like this:

```
TYPE mon_tableau IS VARRAY (2) OF FLOAT;
v_tab  mon_tableau;
```

I give it some values like this:

```
v_tab := mon_tableau (10000, 20000);
```

Then I make a SQL statement that gets the values that I want to update with the two values (10000 and  20000) in my `v_tab`.

How can I do that update? I've tried a cursor in a loop:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE mon_tableau IS VARRAY (2) OF FLOAT;
  v_tab        mon_tableau;
   v_new_prix   RATE_PACK_PARAMETER_VALUE.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT%TYPE;
 CURSOR get_prix
   IS
        SELECT   e.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT
          FROM   mpuzptab a,
                 mpulkgvm b,
                 mpulkrim c,
                 rate_pack_element d,
                 rate_pack_parameter_value e
         WHERE       a.digits IN ('+21685000', '+21685003')

BEGIN
   v_tab := mon_tableau (10000, 20000);
  FOR i IN v_tab.FIRST..v_tab.LAST
   LOOP
      FOR j IN get_prix
      LOOP
         v_new_prix := j.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT;

         UPDATE   rate_pack_parameter_value v
            SET   v_new_prix = v_tab (i)
        WHERE   v.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID = j.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You wan to update a real table using values from a PL/SQL collection? Does it have to be that collection type? How is the table data related to the collection? It would help to show the table structure and maybe some sample date, the update you have attempted, and the result you are looking for.

Comment: Post your code what you have done so far

Comment: You seem to be trying to update every matching row in your table to 10000, then updating it again to 20000. Assuming it has a column called `v_new_prix`, which looks wrong. And your cursor doesn't include `e.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID` which you try to use for the update. What exactly is your goal; and why are you using PL/SQL, rather than a correlated update in plain SQL?

Comment: And ofcourse agreed to Alex..why PL/SQL. it can be done by SQL itself, Is is a part of any specific requirement .

Comment: So really what you are trying to do is set the parameter value corresponding to '+21685000' to 10000, and the value corresponding to '+21685003' to 20000? You still haven't shown the table structures, or how the tables are related, or the data they contain at the start.

Comment: that's right sir - iwant to set the parameter value corresponding to '+21685000' to 10000, and the value corresponding to '+21685003' to 20000'

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the below and try. Post your error as well.

you cursor is missing "

> j.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID

" which you are using later while updating. Select that first before using it.

The below code should work(not tested). Modify the places where mentioned.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE mon_tableau IS VARRAY (2) OF FLOAT;
   v_tab        mon_tableau;
   v_new_prix   RATE_PACK_PARAMETER_VALUE.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT%TYPE;
 CURSOR get_prix
   IS
        SELECT   e.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT,
                 e.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID
          FROM   mpuzptab a,
                 mpulkgvm b,         ---Unnecessary table
                 mpulkrim c,         ---Unnecessary table
                 rate_pack_element d,---Unnecessary table
                 rate_pack_parameter_value e
         WHERE   a.digits IN ('+21685000', '+21685003')
         and    <code>; -----Join your table a & e to avoid cartesian
BEGIN
   v_tab := mon_tableau(10000, 20000);
  FOR i IN v_tab.FIRST..v_tab.LAST
   LOOP
      FOR j IN get_prix
      LOOP
         --v_new_prix := j.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT;

         UPDATE   rate_pack_parameter_value v
            SET   PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT = v_tab(i)
        WHERE    v.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID = j.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thank you sir but actually it updates the two coloumns with the same values wich is 20000 !! is it an order issue ??

Comment: Can you post the table data. If the id of all records  in the table is going to be same then ofcourse it will update the whole table. Also am not updating 2 columns. Which other column are you referring here.

Comment: By lauching this code :         SELECT   e.PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT,
                 e.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID
          FROM   mpuzptab a,
                 mpulkgvm b,         ---Unnecessary table
                 mpulkrim c,         ---Unnecessary table
                 rate_pack_element d,---Unnecessary table
                 rate_pack_parameter_value e
         WHERE   a.digits IN ('+21685000', '+21685003')  , the result is : 90000 with correspand to the value ot the digits +21685000 and 50000 to +21685003 , i want to update the 90000 into 10000 and 50000 into 20000

Comment: So which column is it ? You just need to select that column in your cursor and use it in where clause above. You post your table structure and some sample data

Comment: the column that i want to update is PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT

Comment: You can use the below query to update as needed. The PL/SQL block above will in first iteration will update all ids with 10000 nd in second again update the values to 20000. To do this via pl sql block you need to think again some other logic. Better use a sql .

Comment: UPDATE   rate_pack_parameter_value 
            SET   PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT = case when PARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT = 90000 then
                                                    10000
                                               when ARAMETER_VALUE_FLOAT = 50000 then
                                                    20000
                                           end
        WHERE    v.RATE_PACK_ELEMENT_ID IN ('+21685000', '+21685003')